# How to match and replace elements between two dataframes

Tags: r, dataframe

I need to replace elements from one dataframe values into another dataframe.

For example:

df1:

```
   id  value
0   1     10
1   2     12
2   3     54
3   4     21
```

df2:

```
   col1  col2  col3
0     1     2     3
1     1     1     3
2     1     3     4
3     1     1     5
```

Expected Output:

replaced values from `df1` and applied to `df2`.

```
   col1  col2  col3
0    10    12    54
1    10    10    54
2    10    54    21
3    10    10     5
```

How to do this is in R?

Ill solve this problem in pandas like below,

```
dic=df1.set_index('id')['value'].to_dict()
print df2.replace(dic)
```

But I'm stuck in R.

Please help me to solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can loop through each column of `df2` using `lapply` and find a `match` for `id` column in `df1` and replace the values for the match found using `ifelse` and keep the remaining values as it is.

```
df2[] <- lapply(df2, function(x) {
   inds <- match(x, df1$id)
   ifelse(is.na(inds),x, df1$value[inds]) 
})


df2

#  col1 col2 col3
#0   10   12   54
#1   10   10   54
#2   10   54   21
#3   10   10    5
```

Answer (score 2):

We could do this using named vector after creating a copy of the second dataset.

```
df3 <- df2
df3[] <- setNames(df1$value, df1$id)[as.matrix(df2)]
i1 <- is.na(df3)
df3[i1] <- df2[i1] 
df3
#  col1 col2 col3
#0   10   12   54
#1   10   10   54
#2   10   54   21
#3   10   10    5
```

Comment: your suggested answer not replacing for some of the values in my actual dataset

Comment: @MohamedThasinah  Sorry to hear that.  It is based on the example you showed and it is working fine with it

Answer (score 2):

What you can do:

Make a copy of df2:

```
df3=df2 # in R this is  a copy not as in python
df3[]=df1$value[match(as.matrix(df2),df1$id)] # Match the columns
df3[is.na(df3)]=df2[is.na(df3)] # Reset Na to the previous value
df3
  col1 col2 col3
0   10   12   54
1   10   10   54
2   10   54   21
3   10   10    5
```

Comment: your suggested answer not replacing for some of the values in my actual dataset