# Python For Loops: Optimize speed of code when replacing cat code with original values

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I would like to optimize the speed of the following code:

```
 true_results_str = true_results.astype(str)
 for i in range( 0,len(true_results)): 
     for k in range( 1,true_results.shape[1]): 
         if pd.isna(true_results.iloc[i][k]) == False:
               true_results_str.iat[i,k]=df_data_.Type[df_.cat_code == mapping_item_id[true_results.iloc[i][k]]].item()
```

An example of true_results dataframe is shown below:

```
      user   rec_2  rec_3  
0       16     nan    nan          
1       18      0      4          
2       51      3      0        
3       52      3     nan        
4       58      3      0
```

An example of dictionary mapping_item_id is shown below:

```
Key    Type   Size   Value
0      int64    1      13     
3      int64    1      14     
4      int64    1      15      
6      int64    1      16
```

An example of dataframe df_ is shown below:

```
    _Type              cat_code
    Car                   13
    Shirt                 14
    Tops                  15
    Shoes                 16
```

The dataframe replaced with cat_code from df_:

```
      user   rec_2  rec_3  
0       16     nan     nan         
1       18     13     16          
2       51     14     13        
3       52     14     nan        
4       58     14     13
```

Final true_results_str dataframe should be:

```
      user   rec_2     rec_3  
0       16     nan      nan         
1       18     Car     Shoes          
2       51     Shirt    Car        
3       52     Shirt    nan        
4       58     Shirt    Car   


for test_results of length of 44550
Time Started at :  12262.5898183
Time Stopped at :  12317.2825541
Time Completed at :  54.692735799999355
```

Comment: There is a similar example in R shown https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51439076/how-to-match-and-replace-elements-between-two-dataframes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `mapping_item_id` and `df_` for create final dictioanry and then select all columns without first by [`DataFrame.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) and in lambda function in [`DataFrame.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) use `Series` called `s` for mapping by [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html):

```
d = df_.set_index('cat_code')['_Type'].to_dict()

#if no match return NaN
fin = {k: d.get(v, np.nan) for k, v in mapping_item_id.items()}
print (fin)
{0: 'Car', 3: 'Shirt', 4: 'Tops', 6: 'Shoes'}

true_results.iloc[:, 1:] = true_results.iloc[:, 1:].apply(lambda x: x.map(fin))
print (true_results)
   user  rec_2 rec_3
0    16    NaN   NaN
1    18    Car  Tops
2    51  Shirt   Car
3    52  Shirt   NaN
4    58  Shirt   Car
```

Comment: Thanks I am going to test this out now. Originally the above code took 1hr45mins on a dataframe size of 1.2 million. I will report back on the speed.

Comment: s = mapping_item_id.set_index('Key')['Value'].map(df_.set_index('cat_code')['_Type'])

AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'set_index'

Comment: df_ is a dataframe and mapping_item_id is a dictionary.

Comment: mapping_item_id.set_index('Key')['Value']

AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'set_index'

Comment: Time Started at :  12955.066432
Time Stopped at :  12955.2114821
Time Completed at :  0.1450500999999349    for length of test_results of 44550